# Can we define name as array in submit button?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Can we define name of a submit button as list of array??. If yes then if S1 was clicked the values of the text input should be transfer to one of the input box provided in new div and if S2 was clicked then value should be go below the previous input box. and number of input box in new div depend upon the number of submit button.

```
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" 
 name="Main" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="p1[]" value="">
        <input type="text" name="p1[]" value="">
        <button type="submit" name="S[]">S1</button>
        <button type="submit" name="S[]">S2</button>
        <button type="submit" name="S[]">S3</button>
</form>
<?php
if (isset($_REQUEST['submit'])) {
foreach($_POST['p1'] as $i) 
{
 echo "Hobbies are :".$i."<br>";
}
}
?>
```

Not getting any output from this.

Comment: You don't have `$_REQUEST['submit']` maybe `$_REQUEST['S']`?  Also, why mixing `$_REQUEST` and `$_POST`?

Comment: @AbraCadaver $_REQUEST['S'] also not working.. using $_POST to get value from textbox.

Comment: `print_r($_POST);` but you'll not be able to distinguish between the 3 buttons, you'd need: `name="S[1]" name="S[2]" name="S[3]"` or something.

Comment: Instead of checking for `isset($_REQUEST['submit'])`, have you considered instead checking `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST'`?. This may be more appropriate.

Comment: Separate the `value` attribute of your submit-buttons, and check which one was submitted - do the actions needed based on which one was selected.

Comment: @B.Fleming I just use your method its showing my output. but suppose i want to check the value of text box and depend upon that value should be display.